# Close jQuery Facebox from within Facebox overlay

Tags: jquery

I am trying to close the popup from within the popup that is created by Facebox.

I am performing actions within the popup and when done, I would like it to close itself.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call:

`$(document).trigger('close.facebox');`

Reference [source code](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox/blob/master/src/facebox.js).

Comment: Great that works. Now I have a problem that if I call Facebox multiple times it ajaxs multiple times. I know there is a beforeReveal but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Load your content via manual ajax (e.g. `$.get` or `$.post`), store it in a variable (or inject it in the DOM), then use that for your Facebox content.  In other words, skip the Facebox built-in AJAX.

Comment: Hi, I dont think that will work as I have additional pages loaded once an action is performed and I need the functionality across multiple pages on the site. I.e. I am using Facebox for a register form. When the user submits their details, I replace the register form with a activation form. Once activation is complete I close the Facebox and log the user in. During this register phase there is an 'already a member, log in' section. I need this to be loaded in the same Facebox...same with forgot password. Any other way you can think of fixing the double post issue? Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to create a wrapper `<div>` around the ajax content for the initial screen.  Replace the content in that div instead of opening new boxes.